# ¿Como cambiar los valores de medición de mi gráfica Chart?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

**Hola, mundo.**

Mi problema es que no encuentro la manera de modificar el valor de una gráfica la cual vino integrada en una plantilla que estoy adaptando, pero me encuentro con el problema de que los valores laterales o los de medición de mi gráfica no las puedo cambiar, me aparecen valores por defecto demasiado grandes para lo que busco que es mostrar un promedio con precios (ejemplo: minimo 10$ y como maximo 200$) en ves de valores de registro (la grafica esta orientada a mostrar el estado de usuarios conectados) y posee valores de 100 a 2000, muy grandes para mi objetivo.

Pero me percate de que esta usa una librería llamada Chart y me imagino que se debería  poder configurar aunque aun no he encontrado la forma.

**El código que poseo es:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('estadisticas_ventas').getContext("2d");

gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, '#18ce0f');
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, chartColor);

gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 170, 0, 50);
gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(1, hexToRGB('#18ce0f', 0.4));

myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  responsive: true,
  data: {
    labels: ["12pm,", "3pm", "6pm", "9pm", "12am", "3am", "6am", "9am"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Email Stats",
      borderColor: "#18ce0f",
      pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#18ce0f",
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      pointHoverRadius: 4,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 4,
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: gradientFill,
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [20, 30, 40, 50, 70, 80, 90, 100]
    }]
  },
  options: gradientChartOptionsConfigurationWithNumbersAndGrid
});
```

Comment: Los valores de los ejes se van a ajustar automaticamente dependiendo de tus datos.  Si quieres graficar el promedio tendrias que hacer el calculo y luego substituir los datos con tus nuevos calculos.

Comment: en anyChart hay una función `chart.yScale().minimum(-15);` que permite poner valor inicial en el eje de la **Y** en este caso un **-15**, en chart.js no sé si en el dataset te pueda funcionar de igual forma utilizar el  `yAxisID`.

Comment: Ok entonces estos valores se establecen automáticamente al yo colocar le los datos, y  de todas manera voy a probar el metodo de Vick Muñoz. Gracias.

Comment: @Abraham.P En anyChart igual establece los valores automaticamente, toma el valor mínimo y el máximo de tu array de valores y te crea intervalos dependiendo de los mismos, pero con anyChart también puedes declarar los intervalos, de hecho es una gran biblioteca para crear gráficas, te la recomiendo. [anyChart](https://www.anychart.com/)

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución de mi problema fue sencilla resulta que esta biblioteca determina los valores tomando como base los datos o valores introducidos.

Gracias a Vick Muñoz y alanfcm.